# Rails form calling the wrong method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, haml

I'm new to rails and i'm using the bootstrap simple form to update a user's information but it keeps calling the wrong controller.

Code for the form:

```
simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
= f.input :forename
= f.input :surname
.form-actions
  = f.button :submit, :method => :update
```

Code in the controller:

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    redirect_to wrong_path
end
```

Code in routes:

```
resources :user do
  member do
    post :update
  end
end
```

but in another page I use the form again in a different controller called `AdminController` the `update` form calls the `AdminController` instead of the `UserController`.

What do i need to get it to call the correct controller/

Answer (score 2):

The error is not in the form but rather a lack of understanding of how RESTful routing in rails works.

In the rails conventions you update a record by sending a PATCH request.

```
PATCH /users/:id => user#update
```

In fact when you declare the route:

```
resources :users
```

Rails creates that route for you. Note that the name should be in plural! The same applies to the controller `UsersController` not `UserController`.

When you create a form and pass a resource like so:

```
# sugar on top of form_for
simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
```

Rails will look at the record and try to find a corresponding route based on the conventions. You do not need to specify the method since Rails looks if the model has been persisted.

If you do for for some reason really need to specify the HTTP method you do it on the `<form>` element - not on the submit button.

```
simple_form_for(@user, method: :patch) do |f|
```

Additionally the conventional way to deal with an update route is:

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

You don't want to redirect after a failed form submission - the user will lose any data entered into the form. Rather you want to re-render the form.

Comment: This may sounds silly, but i have no idea what i'm doing. Do I have to add the `PATCH` line in routes?